# PrestaShop translation in email theme

Tags: email, templates, prestashop, translation

I created a specific theme for PrestaShop in *mails > themes* and I would like to add a sentence in the *components > footer.html.twig*

In Classic theme I saw this code:

```
{{ '<a href="{shop_url}">{shop_name}</a> powered by <a href="{prestashop_url}">PrestaShop™</a>'|trans({'{prestashop_url}': 'https://www.prestashop.com/?utm_source=marchandprestashop&utm_medium=e-mail=utm_campaign=footer_1-7'}, 'Emails.Body', locale)|raw }}
```

So I tried to use *trans()* like this:

```
{{ 'My sentence'|trans({}, 'Emails.Body', locale)|raw }}
```

But I've got no clue where I'm supposed to translate it now! I looked in back-office translations but couldn't find it anywhere.

Some help will really be appreciated! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to insert a new row into a `PREFIX_translation` table in your database.

Domain should be typed without a dot, like this: `EmailsBody`.

Unfortunately translations in 1.7 are still a little tricky these days :(

Remember about clearing cache after adding new row into DB.

Comment: Hi @Krystian Podemski, thanks a lot for your answer.

I was a bit lost because in BO theme translation I can now see Emails > Body but PS says "There are no translation file available."

But the translation is working in the email template! Thanks again.